# How to multiply pandas dataframes and preserve row keys

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm struggling with multiplying dataframes together and preserving the row keys.

I have two files, call them say F1 and F2. F1 has a multi-part group key (g1,g2,g3), a two-part Type key (k1,k2) and some weights (r1,r2). F2 has a series of values for each Type key.

I'd like to join them on k1 and k2, and multiply r1 and r2 for each n.

I'm thinking that groupby and dataframe multiply should work but I can't see how to do it. The only thing I've got to work is merge and then multiply column by column, but it's super-slow.

```
F1
g1  g2  g3  k1  k2  r1  r2
A   A   A   A   A   1   2
A   A   A   A   B   3   4
A   A   B   A   B   2   3

F2
k1  k2  n   r1  r2
A   A   1   0   1
A   A   2   1   1
A   A   3   1   0
A   B   1   3   4
A   B   2   4   4
A   B   3   4   3
A   C   1   1   1
A   C   3   4   5
A   C   2   3   4

Result
g1  g2  g3  k1  k2  n   r1  r2
A   A   A   A   A   1   0   2
A   A   A   A   A   2   1   2
A   A   A   A   A   3   1   0
A   A   A   A   B   1   9   16
A   A   A   A   B   2   12  16
A   A   A   A   B   3   12  12
A   A   B   A   B   1   6   12
A   A   B   A   B   2   8   12
A   A   B   A   B   3   8   9
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
mrg = F1.merge(F2, on=['k1', 'k2'])

mrg['r1'] = mrg.filter(like='r1').prod(1)
mrg['r2'] = mrg.filter(like='r2').prod(1)
drops = ['r1_x', 'r1_y', 'r2_x', 'r2_y']
mrg.drop(drops, axis=1)
```

[image]